# MOSFET Replacement for PNP BJT in a 12V switching circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, circuit-design, pnp

I used a PNP to control 12V in circuit. as follows System_Load/2 is 12V DC, MIC1_PWR is the output and LCD_W2/1 is the control signal.

This circuit would work fine if the control signal's High is near the system_laod which is not case so the switch is always ON (when control signal is 0V or 5V)
 [image] .

Can a mosfet be used instead of PNP to overcome this issue?

Comment: No. You will have the same problem if you use a P-channel mosfet. Possibly the easiest thing to do is to use an NPN BJT + either your existing PNP or a P-channel MOSFET. As Andy outlines.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit messy trying to switch 12V on or off with a single transistor from a low voltage logic supply. It can be done using a zener diode in the base circuit. The zener (say 7.5 volts), in effect "shifts" the 5V control signal up so it can fully turn the PNP off.

It's a wee bit harder with a P channel MOSFET because the voltage drive requirements on the gate are usually significantly higher than a BJT.

Of course you could use two transistors quite effectively.

Comment: In a way the P-mosfet is easier if it has a 4.5 gate threshold. That gives you more margin. And, yeah, a 2nd NPN transistor plus a pull-up resistor would be the common garden solution to this. Using a zener is a novel idea although I could see issues with that e.g. does the CMOS output sink current when it's high.